# nightwatch.js assert on multiple page sections

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am working with nightwatch.js
i have a page file that looks like this:

```
sections: {
    table: {
        selector: '.sr-filterable-data-layout--collection',
        elements: {
            header: {
                selector: '.sr-collection--header'
            },
            body: {
                selector: 'sr-collection--body'
            }
        }
    },
    filters: {
        selector: '.sr-filterable-data-layout--filters',
        elements: {
            filterByName: {
                selector: '#filter-name'
            }
        }
    },
    actions: {
        selector: '.sr-entities-actions',
        elements: {
            addButton: {
                selector: '.mdi-content-add'
            }
        }
    }
},
commands: [{
        editEntity(options) {
            return this.section.body();
        },
        verifyPageload() {
            return (
                this.section.filters.waitForElementVisible('@filterByName') 
                    .section.table.waitForElementVisible('@header')
                    // .section.actions.waitForElementVisible('@addButton')
                    .assert.title(this.props.title)
            );
        }
    }
]
```

asserting on each of the elements individually works but when i try to chain the assertions like this:

```
this.section.filters.waitForElementVisible('@filterByName') 
                    .section.table.waitForElementVisible('@header')
```

it fails with the following error:

```
✖ TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForElementVisible' of undefined
```

any help regarding how to chain these asserts together will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while the comments here suggest ways to circumvent the issue. i finally stumbled upon the way to chain multiple actions on different sections by chaining .parent after the first call to return the root of the page and not the section like this:

```
verifyPageload() {
            this.section.table
                .waitForElementVisible('@header')
                .parent.section.filters.waitForElementVisible('@filterByName')
                .parent.section.actions.waitForElementVisible('@addButton')
                .assert.title(this.props.title);
            return this;
        }
```

Comment: that seems utterly cumbersome, you add redundant steps to be executed by the selenium session (traverse back to parent node), and the code is much less readable. further more - the code is rigid and error prone: what if one of the elements changes its location in the dom? you'd have to change your tests accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, as `section` is a **page** property, while `waitForElementVisible` returns a reference to the client instance ("browser"), not to the page.

Just split the commands, there's really no reason to chain them.

Another thing; the `return ()` block is redundant here, just return the assertion result directly:

```
verifyPageload() {
    // waitForStuff...
    return this.assert.title(this.props.title)
}
```

Comment: the reason for chaining as i understood it was asynchronicity.
there is a risk of the return statement happening before the asserts return.

also, when i chain waitForElementVisible without a section; i.e 'this.element.waitForElementVisible' to one another it works fine.

Comment: chaining in the nightwatch API has nothing to do with (a)synchronicity, it's a choice in the API design. the calls are asynchronous regardless as they get sent to the selenium server after the nightwatch engine evaluates all the expressions in your test.